# Django compare query with F objects adds extra not null check

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to query a Django model using F objects but not getting the desired results.
The query is:

`Ticket.objects.exclude(lead__email=F('email')).count()`

Which is translated into SQL by ORM as:

`SELECT count(*) FROM "core_ticket" LEFT OUTER JOIN "core_lead" ON ("core_ticket"."lead_id" = "core_lead"."id") WHERE NOT ("core_lead"."email" = ("core_ticket"."email") AND "core_lead"."email" IS NOT NULL)`

My problem is that ORM adds this `AND "core_lead"."email" IS NOT NULL`  in where clause. which is affecting my results as there can be null values in email field.

Is there a way to avoid this extra not null check.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have `null=True` in your model definition for email. So, the easiest way to fix this is to delete that `null=True`, migrate then try again. Thus, if email is None, it will be `''` instead of `None`, then F() will work.

Another way is to use the Q() query, but it will cost in Python memory.